# Compare two csv and write updated rows to third csv in linux bash terminal

Tags: linux, bash, csv, grep

I am trying to compare two csv and generete only rows that has difference from linux bash terminal
and output it to third csv in bash terminal

grep -v -f csv1 csv2 > csv3

But i am not able to get the rows that are different from csv1 and csv2 rather it prints all rows in csv2

csv1
a,b,c
g,fc

csv2
a,b,c
g,f,c
l,f,c

csv3
l,f,c

This should be the intended output

Comment: At the very least, you should also use `-F`, to avoid the lines of _csv1_ to be interpreted as regular expressions.

Comment: @user1934428 tried this also not working with -F

Comment: Works for me. See [here](https://www.4shared.com/s/fC2S21csLge). Could it be that you have an empty line in csv1? Maybe at the end? Update your question to show a **simple** reproducible example for your problem.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `comm`

Comment: Please add example input and desired output from those inputs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting then [edit] your question to show your input, output, and code as Code Blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it works (Make sure to install panda):

````py
python -c "import pandas as pd; df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv'); df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv'); df_diff = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False); df_diff.to_csv('csv3.csv', index=False)"```
````

Comment: It's working but i don't need sorting the values are sorted . i want it as it is

Comment: is it possible to get the results in same order

Answer (score 1):

Sample files:

```
$ head csv?
==> csv1 <==
1,2,X
4,5,6
7,8,9

==> csv2 <==
1,2,3
a,b,c
7,8,9
```

One `comm / sort` idea:

```
$ comm --output-delimiter="" -3 <(sort csv1) <(sort csv2)
1,2,3
1,2,X
4,5,6
a,b,c
```

Comment: @mark-fuso i just need the rows in csv that are unique when comparing both

Comment: @sysadmincrispy it's not clear (to me) what you mean by *`only rows that has difference`* and *`just need the rows in csv that are unique`*; it would help if you updated the question with some sample files (3-4 rows per file, 3-4 fields per row)

Comment: @sysadmincrispy given the two sample files I've provided, what would you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
head file{1,2}

==> file1 <==
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

==> file2 <==
1,2,3
a,b,c
7,8,9
```

You can use this awk to see which file2 lines are not in file1:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f1[$0]; next}
!($0 in f1)' file1 file2
```

Prints:

```
a,b,c
```

Then reverse the two file inputs if you want the difference from file2 to file1:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f1[$0]; next}
!($0 in f1)' file2 file1
```

Prints:

```
4,5,6
```

Or you could use [daff](https://github.com/paulfitz/daff) for a more complete solution.

Comment: while i replaced my csv if i put file1 second it will show all contents in that if it put file 2 second in that command it shows all contents in file 2 same happens for grep -v -f also

Answer (score 0):

If you have file1.csv

```
a,b,c
g,f,c
```

and file2.csv

```
a,b,c
g,f,c
l,f,c
```

you can run

```
grep -v -F -f file1.csv file2.csv
```

to get

```
l,f,c
```